# Сохраняет пустой файл jpeg , при загрузке с помощью curl

Tags: php, curl

Есть функция загрузки со стороннего сайта картинки

```
function save_image($img,$path){
    $curl = curl_init($img);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    if (file_exists($path)) :
        unlink($path);
    endif;
    $fp = fopen($path,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    fclose($fp);

    return file_exists($path);
}
```

Сохраняет пустой файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только что проверил, функция работает корректно и успешно скачался файл.
Возможно вы неправильно задали url или path.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась добавлением `trim($path)`